# Flutter Riverpod : return 2 stream with StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have music player application using package [Asset Audio Player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) and [Flutter Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) as State Management. I want listen 2 things stream :

1. Listen current duration of song
2. Listen current song played

```
final currentSongPosition = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Map<String, dynamic>>((ref) async* {
  final AssetsAudioPlayer player = ref.watch(globalAudioPlayers).state;
  ref.onDispose(() => player.dispose());

  final Stream<double> _first = player.currentPosition.map((event) => event.inSeconds.toDouble());
  final Stream<double> _second =
      player.current.map((event) => event?.audio.duration.inSeconds.toDouble() ?? 0.0);

  final maps = {};
  maps['currentDuration'] = _first;
  maps['maxDurationSong'] = _second;
  return maps; << Error The return type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' isn't a 'Stream<Map<String, dynamic>>', as required by the closure's context.
});
```

How can i return 2 stream into 1 `StreamProvider` then i can simply using like this :

```
Consumer(
              builder: (_, watch, __) {
               
                final _currentSong = watch(currentSongPosition);

                return _currentSong.when(
                  data: (value) {
                    final _currentDuration = value['currentDuration'] as double;
                    final _maxDuration = value['maxDuration'] as double;
                    return Text('Current : $_currentDuration, Max :$_maxDuration');
                  },
                  loading: () => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Error When Playing Song'),
                );
               
              },
            ),
```

Comment: You should add your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Also, did my answer not work? It addresses your concerns you raised about your solution with rxdart.

Comment: @AlexHartford Your answer work like what i expected, i  only added another approach in my question.

Comment: @AlexHartford and i curious about best practice with my case, it's good to separated StreamProvider like your approach, or we can do with my approach ? The point of my question is, it is more about code efficiency

Comment: I can't promise my answer is "best practice", but it's a durable, easy-to-digest way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating a `StreamProvider` for each `Stream`:

```dart
final currentDuration = StreamProvider.autoDispose<double>((ref) {
  final player = ref.watch(globalAudioPlayers).state;
  return player.currentPosition.map((event) => event.inSeconds.toDouble());
});

final maxDuration = StreamProvider.autoDispose<double>((ref) {
  final player = ref.watch(globalAudioPlayers).state;
  return player.current.map((event) => event?.audio.duration.inSeconds.toDouble() ?? 0.0);
});
```

Next, create a `FutureProvider` to read the last value of each `Stream`.

```dart
final durationInfo = FutureProvider.autoDispose<Map<String, double>>((ref) async {
  final current = await ref.watch(currentDuration.last);
  final max = await ref.watch(maxDuration.last);
  return {
    'currentDuration': current,
    'maxDurationSong': max,
  };
});
```

Finally, create a `StreamProvider` that converts `durationInfo` into a `Stream`.

```dart
final currentSongPosition = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Map<String, double>>((ref) {
  final info = ref.watch(durationInfo.future);
  return info.asStream();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is another approach what @AlexHartford do.

Current solution for my case is using package [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) `CombineLatestStream.list()`, this code should be look then :

### StreamProvider

```
final currentSongPosition = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final AssetsAudioPlayer player = ref.watch(globalAudioPlayers).state;

  final Stream<double> _first = player.currentPosition.map((event) => event.inSeconds.toDouble());
  final Stream<double> _second =
      player.current.map((event) => event?.audio.duration.inSeconds.toDouble() ?? 0.0);

  final tempList = [_first, _second];
  return CombineLatestStream.list(tempList);
});
```

### How to use it :

```
Consumer(
              builder: (_, watch, __) {
                final players = watch(globalAudioPlayers).state;
                final _currentSong = watch(currentSongPosition);
                return _currentSong.when(
                  data: (value) {
                    final _currentDuration = value[0];
                    final _maxDuration = value[1];
                    return Slider.adaptive(
                      value: _currentDuration,
                      max: _maxDuration,
                      onChanged: (value) async {
                        final newDuration = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                        await players.seek(newDuration);
                        context.read(currentSongProvider).setDuration(newDuration);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
                );
              },
            ),
```

> But this approach have drawback, the code is hard to readable. Especially when use in `Consumer`, I have to know the order of return result.